# How to filter multiple column filter using OR operation in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

Using Ag-grid I want to filter multiple columns with OR operation without external filter. Usually the grid supports AND operation when doing filter on multiple columns but I need OR operation to get result for both values on the grid.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)